# Regarding Azure IoMT FHIR Connector

Tags: azure

I require few clarification  regarding Azure IoMT FHIR connector and Azure FHIR API.
   I understanding IoMT connector does have inbuild event hub and if I configured our edge device(which is actually collecting observation from Medical device(PHD) to forward the raw data on HTTPS to Event Hub integrated in IoMT FHIR connector for ingestion
o   Is the understanding correct? Or do we really have to connect the device first with IOT HUB and then only Event hub part of IOTM FHIR connector for data ingestion
o   Is IoMT connector has stream analyzer which can enable us to analyze the stream. Using which we can define a custom Business logic to take some action based on reading pattern 
 ( e.g., on receiving high glucose reading multiple time, will lead to notify the care givers/practitioner about the same)? 
o   Is IoMT connector provide any provision to store the raw data we are receiving from Device in blob storage for audit or any other purpose later?
   I assume, we can forward the transformed data to FHIR API directly from connector, is it correct?